# Given any sequence of minimizing segments, can we find a converged subsequence?

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

This question comes from a paper I read. Assume $M$ is a finitely connected, complete, noncompact 2-D Riemannian manifold with one end.

> Where the finitely connected with one end means that $M$ is homeomorphic to a $N-\{p\}$ ($N$ is a compact manifold and $p\in N$)

For an arbitrarily fixed simple closed smooth curve $c$, let $\sigma:[0,\infty)\to M$ be a ray of $M$ and $\{t_j\}$ be a monotone and divergent nonnegative sequence. Let $\gamma_j$ be a minimizing segment from $c$ to $\sigma(t_j)$.

> Where a ray $\gamma$ of $M$ means that for any nonnegetive number $a<b$, $\gamma|_{[a,b]}$ always is minimizing segment.

My question is there exists a subsequence $\{\gamma_k\}$ of $\{\gamma_j\}$ converge to some ray $\gamma$ of $M$? And How? Or does there exist any reference I can refer to? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to look at is convergence of the initial velocity vectors. Assume that each of the geodesics $\gamma_j$ is given a unit-speed parametrization, with $\gamma_j(0)\in c$, $|\gamma'_j(0)|=1$, and $\gamma_j(b_j)=\sigma(t_j) $ where $b_j = d(c,\sigma(t_j))$. The set of unit tangent vectors at points of $c$ is compact, so a subsequence of the vectors $\gamma'_j(0)$ converges to a unit vector $v$ at some point of $c$. Let $\gamma$ be the geodesic with initial velocity $v$. By continuity of the exponential map, $\gamma_j(t)$ converges to $\gamma(t)$ for each $t\in \mathbb R$. Assume also that $\sigma$ is unit-speed.

Note that
\begin{align*}
t_j &=
d(\sigma(0), \sigma(t_j))\\
&\le d(\sigma(0),c) + d(c, \sigma(t_j))\\
&= d(\sigma(0),c) + b_j,
\end{align*}
which shows that $b_j \nearrow +\infty$.

To see that $\gamma|_{[0,\infty)}$ is a ray, let $b\in [0,\infty)$ be arbitrary. As soon as $j$ is large enough that $b_j>b$, the fact that $\gamma_j|_{[0,b_j]}$ is minimizing means that $d(\gamma_j(0),\gamma_j(b)) = b$. Thus by continuity of the distance function,
$$
d(\gamma(0),\gamma(b)) = \lim_{j\to\infty} d(\gamma_j(0),\gamma_j(b)) = b,
$$
showing that the restriction of $\gamma$ to $[0,b]$ is minimizing for each $b$, i.e., that $\gamma$ is a ray.